# Inverse matrices equality

Tags: matrices

Suppose I have:

$$X = Z^{-1} Y Z$$

Where all are matrices, Z is invertible, can I conclude $$X = Y$$? Or is this not correct as matrix multiplication isnt commutative?

Comment: No, you cannot. The equation you wrote says that $X$ is similar to $Y$. For example, every symmetric matrix is similar to a diagonal matrix, without being equal to it, necessarily.

Comment: This would be incorrect. If you're doing a linear algebra course, you'll learn that X and Y are $similar$ but not equal. This is the basis for an eigenvalue decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not true. Already for matrices of size $2$ we see that for
$$
X=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix},\; Y=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
$$
there exists an invertible matrix $Z$ such that $X=Z^{-1}YZ$. Obviously, $X\neq Y$.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to make that conclusion. Since matrix multiplication is noncommutative, you have to think of it in terms of right and left multiplication. We can show that $$ZX=YZ$$ by right multiplying on each side of the equation by $Z$, but it is not in general true that $X=Y$ in this case.